# Empty Rails application - Memory not decreasing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory, memory-leaks

I am having a memory leak on my app, so I decided to test the memory behavior on an empty RoR app and having only the skeleton created by ***rails new myApp*** an running the app and doing requests, I can see the memory RSS going slowly up and never decreasing.

I tested using some combinations of Rails and Ruby versions and always the behavior was similar.

I have used Thin, Puma, Unicorn, Rainbows, to always get similar results

[image]

Any thoughts? I find it very weird.

Comment: Read [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/ruby-uses-memory/) to see how ruby uses memory :)